# Background Image isn't appearing on my website

Tags: css, html, background, background-image

I tried everything from changing the folders,renaming, checking for typos.

I first tried adding it to a css class

below is my last attempt trying it on the HTML sheet

```
    <div> <nav class="Article">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td data-bg="Artboard-10.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </nav>
        </div>
    <div>
```

The body background image is working fine its just trying to add other background images into elements as a table or a section isnt working.

this is the CSS code I initially added

```
.Article table tr td{
background: url("Photos/Artboard-10.png") no-repeat;
```

}

Please help!

Comment: What is the link to your website?

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: does the element you are adding the background to have any 'height'? the table in your question has no content and so there would be no height by default.

Comment: A code snippet inside the post would help people help you. Need to see your CSS as well.

Comment: The problem really isnt trying to add the background image in the a table cell, but any background image I add besides the body code (shown below) isn't working

body{
    background: url(Homepage-bg.png);
    background-size:100%; }

Answer (score 0):

An image as background.

```css
.article .image {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/257540/pexels-photo-257540.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=300&w=200") center no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  height: 267px;
}
```

```html
<div> 
  <nav class="article">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="image">
          &nbsp
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

But it isn't working at all 

I'm so clueless what to do :(

Comment: It seems that my IDE isn't recognizing the background tag, the code works fine. Time to switch to a new IDE. ;)